Terragrunt: get local variable values from certain files down (not up) the directory tree
For this terragrunt directory structure:
project
  environment-dev
    _common
      region
        apps
          app-a
            subenv.hcl
          app-b
            subenv.hcl
          app-c
            subenv.hcl
          ... # other apps can be added in the future
          app-x
            subenv.hcl
    account.hcl

and in each subenv.hcl file there is (among other config) this snipet:
  # tags
  app_tags = {
    "App_tag" = "app-x"
  }

I would like to have in the account.hcl a local variable called app_name which values is input manually but to add a validation for this value, https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/custom-conditions#input-variable-validation. This validation to only allow a value for app_name in the account.hcl from the values of App_tag of each subenv.hcl file down the directory tree.
I was thinking to use read_terragrunt_config with 'find_in_parent_folders', https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/reference/built-in-functions/#read_terragrunt_config but 'find_in_parent_folders' searches up the directory tree and not down; the account.hcl file should get variable values from files which are down the tree and also from all of the files found down the directory tree.
Thank you.

There aren't any commands for searching down the directory tree. Are you showing the whole folder structure? Is there any terragrunt.hcl file in these folders/subfolders?

You can only use statically defined include configuration block, meaning for every app-n you'll have to add include to your account.hcl.
It would be easier to store app_name constraints higher in the hierarchy and refer it in account.hcl and in subenv.hcls
